# How to exclude one project from automatic build in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, build

How to exclude one project from automatic build in Eclipse?

I have one project in workspace, which is probably builds very long (even if nothing was changed). I want to keep this project opened to browse source code but I need not it is being build all the time.

How to disable automatic build for this project?

Probably this was a bug in Eclipse https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=60803 and it was solved long time ago. Unfortunately, I can't find any per project options to control automatic build.

Answer (score 12):

When you open the Project properties of the project that should not be built you can disable all Builders - especially the "Java Builder". This should prevent any automated action like compiling regarding the project.

Comment: Won't builder deselection disable manual build possibility too?

Comment: I assume so, but you said you only want to keep it open for browsing the source code. Therefore manual building is not needed in your case (base on what you wrote in your question).

Comment: But I referred to a bug entry, where another details were presented. I wonder, if this bug was solved, then where is the solution? How to access this solution?

Answer (score 4):

An easier solution is to "Close Project" on the projects that you don't want to Build.  I tried deselecting the Builders for the project, but this didn't work.  Close Project on sample code, unused  libraries and other "non-dependencies" allowed me to work with only the Projects of concern in the Package Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use the `Inclusion` and `Exclusion Patterns` option in the Java Build Path. 
For example if you want to exclude one project from being automatically built: 
1- Go to its Properties->Java Build Path->Source. 
2- Expand the folder in the "Source folders on the build path:" area 
3- Select Exclude->Edit 
4- In the exclusion patterns add ** 
Note: for more information on this patterns: [Include and Exclusion Patterns](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-inclusion-exclusion-patterns.htm&cp=1_2_1_0_0)

Comment: As an alternative: Right-click on the source directory to be excluded → "Build Path" → "Exclude".