# How can I prevent Eclipse from auto-rebuilding when I edit certain files?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I'm developing a Java application using Eclipse Luna. I began looking into Ant scripts earlier today to develop a way of producing version numbers for the software as it changes. I'm pretty happy with it so far but the one remaining issue I seem to have is that I have an Ant script `build.xml` which modifies the build number of a property file `build_info.properties` whenever Eclipse recompiles the source code.

However, I've set Eclipse to rebuild automatically which means that any changes made to what it considers as the project's source files invokes this recompilation process, and so when `build_info.properties` is modified, it causes everything to be recompiled again in a feedback loop.

What I'm wondering is if there's a way I can prevent this from happening *while still having auto-rebuild enabled* such that Eclipse won't recompile everything every time that `build_info.properties` changes?

I've looked at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589021/how-to-exclude-one-project-from-automatic-build-in-eclipse) but Robert's answer is not applicable to my situation and Javi's answer doesn't appear to work for me (I tried putting `build_info.properties` in its own source folder and setting the folder's exclusion pattern to `**`).

The relevant parts of `build.xml` are given below:

```
<target name="compile" depends="updateRevision">
    <echo>Compiling...</echo>
    <antcall target="build">
    </antcall>
</target>

<target name="updateRevision" if="git.present">
    <exec executable="git" outputproperty="git.hash" failifexecutionfails="true" errorproperty="">
        <arg value="rev-parse" />
        <arg value="HEAD" />
    </exec>
    <propertyfile file="${propertyfile.name}">
        <entry key="build.revision.number" type="string" operation="=" value="${git.hash}" />
    </propertyfile>
</target>

<target name="build" depends="updateRevision">
    <propertyfile file="${propertyfile.name}">
        <entry key="build.build.number" type="int" operation="+" value="1" />
    </propertyfile>
</target>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this but in different cases where behavior should change for specific resources Eclipse checks whether the resource is marked as being derived. So you could try and mark the properties file as derived (Properties of the resource, there's a checkbox).

Comment: @Thomas That didn't seem to work, I'm afraid.