# Ant script no longer invoked when source files modified in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

**Summary**
I'm developing a Java application within Eclipse Luna. I've been trying to develop an Ant script that will increment my project's version number whenever I recompile the source code. However, my script is not being invoked when the source files change.

**Details**
As a follow-on to [this problem I was having yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633627/how-can-i-prevent-eclipse-from-auto-rebuilding-when-i-edit-certain-files), I tried to solve the issue by enabling `Specify working set of relevant resources` under `Properties -> Builders -> {Ant builder} -> Edit -> Build Options` and setting the working set to include all of my source files. Eclipse's documentation says that this will cause the Ant script to be invoked if any of those files are modified. After doing that, I removed all target calls from `Auto Build` under `Targets`.

For all of 60 seconds, this seemed to work; my Ant script would be invoked and increment the version number whenever I made a change to a source file and hit save, and it didn't cause a feedback loop as when I had it invoked within `Auto Build`.

I then tried unchecking `Allocate Console` under `Build Options` to see if I could get the script to run silently. This stopped it from working, so I re-enabled it. However, it still didn't work after doing that, and even closing and re-opening Eclipse hasn't solved that.

This is pretty annoying and unintuitive behaviour. Is it a bug or am I missing something? I would like Eclipse to invoke my Ant script whenever I modify the source files, but not in a way that causes it to enter a feedback loop where modifying files leads to a recompilation which modifies my `build_info.properties` file, which leads to further recompilation, ad nauseum.

I'd be happy to provide any additional information should it be required.

**EDIT**
I tried creating a new test project with a copy of the build script and configuring it to run for that. It did not work in the new project either.

My test project structure:

[image]

My build configuration:

[image]

The working set of relevant resources for my ant script:

[image]

My complete build script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="buildscript" default="compileView">

    <available file=".git" type="dir" property="git.present" />

    <property name="propertyfile.name" value="ant/build_info.properties" />
    <property file="${propertyfile.name}" />
    <property name="build.number" value="v${build.major.number}.${build.minor.number}.${build.build.number}.r${build.revision.number}" />

    <target name="current-number">
        <echo>Current build number: ${build.number}</echo>
    </target>

    <!-- Set this as default -->
    <target name="compileView">
        <antcall target="compile">
        </antcall>
        <antcall target="current-number">
        </antcall>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="updateRevision">
        <echo>Compiling...</echo>
        <antcall target="build">
        </antcall>
    </target>

    <target name="dist" depends="updateRevision">
        <echo>Producing redistributable</echo>
        <antcall target="minor">
        </antcall>
        <antcall target="createJar">
        </antcall>
    </target>

    <target name="createJar" depends="updateRevision">
        <property name="projectHome" location="." />
        <jar destfile="<<redacted>>.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="<<redacted>>.Main" />
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="." />
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="${projectHome}/bin" />
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="${projectHome}/forms-1.3.0.jar" />
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="${projectHome}/miglayout15-swing.jar" />
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="C:/Users/<<redacted>>/Documents/eclipse/plugins/org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030/junit.jar" />
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="C:/Users/<<redacted>>/Documents/eclipse/plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar" />
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="updateRevision" if="git.present">
        <exec executable="git" outputproperty="git.hash" failifexecutionfails="true" errorproperty="">
            <arg value="rev-parse" />
            <arg value="HEAD" />
        </exec>
        <propertyfile file="${propertyfile.name}">
            <entry key="build.revision.number" type="string" operation="=" value="${git.hash}" />
        </propertyfile>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="updateRevision">
        <propertyfile file="${propertyfile.name}">
            <entry key="build.build.number" type="int" operation="+" value="1" />
        </propertyfile>
    </target>

    <target name="minor" depends="updateRevision">
        <propertyfile file="${propertyfile.name}">
            <entry key="build.minor.number" type="int" operation="+" value="1" />
            <entry key="build.build.number" type="int" value="0" />
        </propertyfile>
    </target>

    <target name="major" depends="updateRevision">
        <propertyfile file="${propertyfile.name}">
            <entry key="build.major.number" type="int" operation="+" value="1" />
            <entry key="build.minor.number" type="int" value="0" />
            <entry key="build.revision.number" type="int" value="0" />
        </propertyfile>
    </target>

</project>
```

The script runs fine if I invoke it manually:

```
Buildfile: W:\<<redacted>>\workspace\TestProject\build.xml

compileView:

updateRevision:

compile:
        [echo] Compiling...

updateRevision:

build:
[propertyfile] Updating property file: W:\<<redacted>>\workspace\TestProject\ant\build_info.properties

current-number:
        [echo] Current build number: v0.0.2.r0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 143 milliseconds
```

Comment: Did you check the error log?

Comment: @AaronDigulla I'm pretty new to working with Ant scripts. Do you mean the log file in `{my workspace}\.metadata` or is there a different one?

Comment: The one in `.metadata`. Eclipse also has an "Error View" where you can see the errors logged. Maybe there is an error in the Ant script which prevents Eclipse from executing it.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Thanks. Eclipse reports no errors from today related to my Ant script either in Error View or in the `.metadata` log. Additionally, I'm able to execute the Ant script just fine if I run it manually, it's just that it's not automatically running when I modify my source files.

Comment: Did you try to delete everything from your build (look into the `.project` and `.classpath` files, too) and recreate the whole setup?

Comment: @AaronDigulla I tried creating a new project altogether with the build script. It still doesn't seem to work. I've updated the OP.

Comment: I still can't see any mistake on your side. Can you add logging to the Ant script to see whether Eclipse tries to execute it at all? Also try to configure it without the resource filter.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Sorry for the late response. I think I'm going to abandon this method of version numbering in favour one that's compatible with the Git Flow workflow strategy here: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Thank you for your help.